# Get data from database and build up a string to use for JSON

Tags: c#, json

I want to return all my data from database and build up a string, or I want to loop and write results to Json.

My code is as follows:

```
public string GetNewTickets()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select LoggedDate, count(ID) as ticketAmount from Tickets WHERE LoggedDate >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0) AND State = '1' group by LoggedDate"))
        {
            var ticketAmount = 0;
            var loggedDate = DateTime.Now;
            var ActualloggedDate = string.Empty;
            var convertedLoggedDate = string.Empty;

            var test = string.Empty;

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ticketAmount = (int)reader["ticketAmount"];
                    //Convert to JSON format
                    loggedDate = (DateTime)reader["LoggedDate"];
                    ActualloggedDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loggedDate, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
                    convertedLoggedDate = ActualloggedDate.Substring(1, ActualloggedDate.Length - 4);
                }
            }
            var entity = new
            {
                ticketAmount = ticketAmount,
                loggedDate = convertedLoggedDate,
            };
            var json = serializer.Serialize(entity);
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

This returns only one row in json

```
{"ticketAmount":1,"loggedDate":"2016-09-16T08:03:"}
```

I have about 10 records in my database and I want to return all the nessesary ones. Result should be something like

```
{"ticketAmount":1,"loggedDate":"2016-09-16T08:03:"}, 
{"ticketAmount":5,"loggedDate":"2016-09-17T08:03:"},
{"ticketAmount":4,"loggedDate":"2016-09-18T08:03:"}
```

Comment: Add this `var json += serializer.Serialize(entity);` inside the `while` and declare the `var entity` before the `if`.

Comment: Before if - `var entity = string.Empty;`
in While - `var json = serializer.Serialize(entity);`
How would I then use the `var entity = new
                    {
                        ticketAmount = ticketAmount,
                        loggedDate = convertedLoggedDate,
                    };`

Comment: `var json += serializer.Serialize(entity);` look at it carefully... it's concatenating the strings using `+=`...so use it inside the `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return multiple JSON objects (one for each row) you can return an JSON array, like this:

```
[
    {"ticketAmount":1,"loggedDate":"2016-09-16T08:03:"}, 
    {"ticketAmount":5,"loggedDate":"2016-09-17T08:03:"},
    {"ticketAmount":4,"loggedDate":"2016-09-18T08:03:"}
]
```

By using

```
var json = serializer.Serialize(entity);
return json;
```

your program serializes exactly one entity (the last one) regardless of how many matching records exists. Therefore I recommend to store all matching entites in a `List` and serialize the `List` object. E.g:

```
public class EntityDto {
    public int ticketAmount {get; set;}
    public DateTime loggedDate {get; set;}
}

...

public string GetNewTickets()
{
    var entities = new List<EntityDto>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select LoggedDate, count(ID) as ticketAmount from Tickets WHERE LoggedDate >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0) AND State = '1' group by LoggedDate"))
        {
            var ticketAmount = 0;
            var loggedDate = DateTime.Now;
            var ActualloggedDate = string.Empty;
            var convertedLoggedDate = string.Empty;

            var test = string.Empty;

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ticketAmount = (int)reader["ticketAmount"];
                    //Convert to JSON format
                    loggedDate = (DateTime)reader["LoggedDate"];
                    ActualloggedDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loggedDate, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
                    convertedLoggedDate = ActualloggedDate.Substring(1, ActualloggedDate.Length - 4);
                    var entity = new EntityDto
                     {
                         ticketAmount = ticketAmount,
                         loggedDate = convertedLoggedDate,
                     };
                    entites.Add(entity);
                }
            }

        }            
    }
    var json = serializer.Serialize(entities);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Cant edit post but I chnaged my code to `public string loggedDate {get; set;}` also look at var `var entites = new List<EntityDto>();` and change it to `entities`, Thanks